# Is it possible to have customer sign with usernames instead of emails in Shopify?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

If anyone know of a shopify app that does this, please advise! I have been looking into documentations and apps for this particular feature, but no luck. If any questions, please let me know.

Comment: Shopify doesn't have usernames. They have first and last name, but that is not unique. You can have the same first and last name, but a different email which will set a login issue.The username is the email address since that is the unique value that can't be repeated. So if this is a client request you should decline it as not logical.

Comment: So basically, what I am trying to see is if it is possible for them to sign up with user names or ids(not their names) instead of emails. Please let me know if this makes sense and if this is feasible or logical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set this up with Shopify Plus. Shopify Plus has a feature they call "multi-pass" that allows external login. Part of the handshake there is an email address but if your external system doesn't have that you can fake one.

Comment: Can this be tested with the shopify partners development store? I see it enabled there, but the documentations is not sufficient. Please advise